# Validation detected dangerous client input - post from TinyMCE in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scripting, tinymce

I get this error when I post from [TinyMCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyMCE) in an ASP.NET MVC view.

Error:

> **Request Validation has detected a potentially dangerous client input value, and processing of the request has been aborted**

From googling, it says to just add a validateRequest in the Page directive at the top which I did, but I STILL get this error.  As you can see, below is my code in the view:

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the decorator `[ValidateInput(false)]`.

You will then want to write a HTMLEncode method to make it safe.

Let me know if you want me to post the one I use.

Added the Encode I use

```
    public static class StringHelpers
{
    public static string HtmlEncode(this string value)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            value = value.Replace("<", "&lt;");
            value = value.Replace(">", "&gt;");
            value = value.Replace("'", "&apos;");
            value = value.Replace(@"""", "&quot;");
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static string HtmlDecode(this string value)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            value = value.Replace("&lt;", "<");
            value = value.Replace("&gt;", ">");
            value = value.Replace("&apos;", "'");
            value = value.Replace("&quot;", @"""");
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you can post that would be great

Comment: thanks.. that worked great.  is there anyway to prepoulate the textarea from an existing html page

Comment: Don't quite understand what you mean [me].  Are you talking about screen scraping here or...

Comment: Worth noting two things if using VS2010 and ASP.NET MVC2.  First of all, you need to put <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /> within <system.web> in your web.config file for the [ValidateInput(false)] attribute to work.  Secondly, the above encoder is far too naive to be reliable.

Comment: What's wrong with using `HttpUtility` for `HtmlEncode`/decode rather than writing your own?

Answer (score 9):

Try this solution. simply add to TinyMce control

```
tinyMCE.init({
...
encoding : "xml"
});
```

http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/encoding

http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2010/07/22/96.aspx

Comment: unfortunately tinymce 4 seems to have dropped this

Answer (score 5):

Try using the `[AllowHtml]` attribute in your model.

```
class MyModel{
 [AllowHtml]
 public string Content{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly in version 4 of tinymce they seem to have removed the encoding: xml option.

I ended up using a javascript HTML encoding function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery), and on my submit button I encode the contents of the textarea before the form submits, by using tinymce's getContent and setContent methods

Comment: I think it's risky to depend solely on client side encoding, as it doesn't prevent an evildoer from POSTing directly to your site. You have to sanitize inputs on the server as well.

Comment: Yes it's important to always remember that

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I didn't want to disable ASP.NET MVC validation feature, so I kept looking until I reached this solution:

At the tinyMCE plugin code encode your content (I'm using the older version)

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   encoding: "xml"
});
```

And after this I didn't get any more the application validation error. Then I came up with another problem when I edited my form the code would come up with the html tags

```
<strong>My input value</strong>
```

instead of this

**My input value**

So, I had to decode the html for that field when getting my values at the Controller, like this:

```
...    
entity.field = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(entity.field);
```