# Encode HTML before POST

Tags: html, jquery, post, html-encode

I have the following script, which encodes some of the value it receives propertly, but it does not seem to encode double quotes.

How do I encode the full value properly before posting?

```
function htmlEncode(value){ 
    return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); 
}
```

The above script give me this:

```
&lt;p&gt;Test&amp;nbsp; &lt;span style="color: #ffffff"&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;span style="background-color: #ff0000"&gt;1+1+1=3&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

I need it to give me this:

```
&lt;p&gt;Test&amp;nbsp; &lt;span style=&quot;color: #ffffff&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;background-color: #ff0000&quot;&gt;1+1+1=3&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

EDIT: Followup question:
[Encoded HTML in database back to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899365/encoded-html-in-database-back-to-page)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to get the client to make some text HTML safe before submitting it to the server. Don't do that. Make content HTML safe on the way out of the system, not on the way in (and especially not on the client, where it can be tampered with)

Comment: Why do you need to do it JS on the client?

Comment: Why do you want it to give you `&quot;` anyway? Unless you are planning to insert the data into an attribute value (that you mash together using strings instead of using a DOM or other sensible API) then you're just using 6 bytes when 1 will do and making it harder to read.

Comment: I tried sending the server html, but it did not like it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897441/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form

Comment: see this link http://www.tumuski.com/code/htmlencode/

Comment: You've been given bad advice. You should turn off the over-sensitive filter so you can get the data you want to receive (and then handle it carefully to protect yourself from XSS).

Comment: Follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899365/encoded-html-in-database-back-to-page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't try to encode things with JavaScript.

You should encode it serverside.

Anything that can be done with JavaScript can be undone.

It is valid to encode it in JavaScript if you also check that it was encoded on the server, but keep in mind: **JavaScript can be disabled.**

Comment: I tried posting standard html to the server, but i get an error saying that i am trying to do cross site scripting or something along those lines.  Here is a link when I tried to send html to the server without encoding it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897441/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form

Comment: @oshirowanen I guess you are using `vb.net`, you have to disable the page validation to be able to get the content as is.

Comment: What are you using as your server side language?

Comment: Follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899365/encoded-html-in-database-back-to-page

Comment: there are perfectly valid times to encode with javascript, such as when you want to NOT trigger asp.net's XSS detection when you post <x  newer 'decent' wysiwyg editors will do this (And rightfully so) so request validation doesn't have to be disabled

Comment: @AdamTuliper You're quite right, but JavaScript can be disabled. Whether or not you encode it in JavaScript, you must also run it through serverside encoding.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker agreed, but your comment was to not encode things with javascript, and there are 100% valid times to do this prior to posting. In this case I mentioned you would not want to encode on the server side, the purpose is to encode to bypass restrictions of posting html without disabling request validation. Data generally shouldnt be stored encoded but sanitized otherwise you are open to double encoding issues.

Answer (score 5):

What [George says is true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4899046/16587).
But, if you have to encode strings client-side, I'd suggest you use JavaScript's [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Comment: `The escape and unescape functions are deprecated. Use encodeURI, encodeURIComponent, decodeURI or decodeURIComponent to encode and decode escape sequences for special characters. ` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_Features

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I simply used the replace method in javascript. Here's a nice article to read: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Basically what the replace method does is it swaps or replaces the character it founds with what you indicate as replacement character(s).

So this:

```
var str=' " That " ';
str = str.replace(/"/g,'&quot;');
```

Once you log this into the console of your browser, you will get something like

```
&quot; That &quot;
```

And this:

```
var str=' " That " ';
str = str.replace(/"/g,'blahblahblah');
```

Once you log this into the console of your browser, you will get something like

```
blahblahblah That blahblahblah
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module in js, without requiring jQuery:

[htmlencode](http://www.tumuski.com/code/htmlencode/)

Answer (score 0):

You can re-use functions from php.js project - [htmlentities](http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities:425) and [get_html_translation_table](http://phpjs.org/functions/get_html_translation_table:416)

Comment: It really should be done server-side. Anyway, you should use `htmlspecialchars()` instead of `htmlentities()`.

Answer (score -1):

Use escape(str) at client side

and

HttpUtility.UrlDecode(str, System.Text.Encoding.Default); at server side

it worked for me.

Comment: I not sure you understood the question, and this is specifically asking for client-side code to be submitted to the server. It also does not mention the server at all, so the server code you've included could very likely not be relevant.

Comment: Yes, Andrew you right. I have given him a trick for client side encoding. and additionally i have suggested him how to handle it at server side, if it is necessary,