# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client for mandrill webhook

Tags: model-view-controller

I am using this for handle bounce mails on our server

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public string Mandrill(FormCollection fc)
    {
    string json = fc["mandrill_events"];
    }
```

but I am getting this error 
**System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (mandrill_events="...550 5.1.1 ...").**

Please help for solve this issue.

Comment: You can set ValidateRequest= false as mentioned in this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17380462/4547684)