# Forum not showing HTML from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, forum

I have another problem with this forum. Everything is working good, just not posting HTML.

When I post threads without any html it shows on the thread view, but if I post stuff with html, bold etc it won't show at all.

Heres the post file

```
<?php

include "connect.php"; //connection string

if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{

   $name=$_POST['name'];

   $yourpost=$_POST['yourpost'];

   $subject=$_POST['subject'];

   if(strlen($name)<1)

   {

      print "You did not type in a name."; //no name entered

   }

   else if(strlen($yourpost)<1)

   {

      print "You did not type in a post."; //no post entered

   }

   else if(strlen($subject)<1)

   {

      print "You did not enter a subject."; //no subject entered

   }

   else

   {

      $thedate=date("U"); //get unix timestamp

      $displaytime=date("F j, Y, g:i a");

      //we now strip HTML injections

      $subject=strip_tags($subject);

      $name=strip_tags($name);

      $yourpost=strip_tags($yourpost); 

      $insertpost="INSERT INTO forumtutorial_posts(author,title,post,showtime,realtime,lastposter) values('$name','$subject','$yourpost','$displaytime','$thedate','$name')";

      mysql_query($insertpost) or die("Could not insert post"); //insert post

      print "Message posted, go back to <A href='index.php'>Forum</a>.";

   }



}

else

{

   print "<form action='post.php' method='post'>";

   print '<input type="hidden" name="name" value="' . $_SESSION[usr_name] . '" size="20"><br>';

   print "Topic title:<br>";

   print "<input type='text' name='subject' size='20'><br>";

   print "Your message:<br>";

   print "<textarea name='yourpost' rows='5' cols='40' id='new_thread'></textarea><br>";

   print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'></form>";



}

?>
<script language="JavaScript">
  generate_wysiwyg('new_thread');
</script>
```

And here is the thread view

```
<?php 

include "connect.php"; //mysql db connection here

$id=$_GET['id'];

$gettopic="SELECT * from forumtutorial_posts where postid='$id'";

$gettopic2=mysql_query($gettopic) or die("Could not get topic");

$gettopic3=mysql_fetch_array($gettopic2);

print "<div id='left'>";

print "<div id='navi-body'>";

print "<a href='index.php'>Back to main forum</a> <a href='post.php'>New Topic</a> <A href='reply.php?id=$id'>Reply</a>";

print "</div>";

print "<div class='content'>";

print "<div class='content-header yellow'>$gettopic3[title]</div>";

print "<div class='content-mid'>";

$message=strip_tags($gettopic3['post']);

$message=nl2br($message);

print "$message";

print "<br /><br />";

print "Posted by: $gettopic3[author] Created at: $gettopic3[showtime]";

print "</div>";

print "<div class='content-footer'></div>";

print "</div>";

$getreplies="Select * from forumtutorial_posts where parentid='$id' order by postid desc"; //getting replies

$getreplies2=mysql_query($getreplies) or die("Could not get replies");

while($getreplies3=mysql_fetch_array($getreplies2))

{

   print "<div class='content'>";

   print "<div class='content-header yellow'>$getreplies3[author] replied at $getreplies3[showtime]</div>";

   print "<div class='content-mid'>";

   $message=strip_tags($getreplies3['post']);

   $message=nl2br($message);

   print "$message";

   print "</div>";

   print "<div class='content-footer'></div>";

   print "</div>";

}

print " ";



?>
```

I want it to show HTML and non html.

Comment: Please show an example of what is being posted, what is being returned - both in MySQL and then in PHP.

Comment: Hi Blowski, In mysql the "post" bit is blanked, but everything else is filled in correctly.

Comment: And I hope this is just dummy code, as your inputs right now are completely insecure. You should really look into PDOs.

Comment: And when I look at the source of the page it is blank too. Only with HTML ;/

Comment: And thanks for pointing that out Blowski.. i will look at tutorials. :)

Comment: What are the actual values in the database? What are you *expecting* it to show? It would be easiest if, in your question, you say "When I post this { code sample }, { this } is saved in the database, { this } is returned from the database, and { this } is shown on the page. Do the same for both when it is working, and when it isn't. Use a small simple example.

Comment: Okay sorry Blowski. I'm expecting it to show HTML. For example, I wanted it to show a picture I posted. When I try to make it bold, or add images etc it will send a blank to mysql.

Comment: But if I use it without the editor it works perfectly. Shows in database and on thread view!

Comment: You need to show the exact inputs and responses. Without those, the question is too vague.

Answer (score 1):

..but you have the strip_tags() function there which stripes any HTML or PHP tags from the string (post).

```
$message=strip_tags($getreplies3['post']);
```

You may want to use the second part of this function and add some extra parameters for those tags you would like to allow. (like BOLD, ITALICS, etc.)

```
$message_with_some_html = strip_tags($getreplies3['post'], '<strong><em>');
```

I hope I am right, please check PHP docs... :)

Also you may want to sterilize the $_POST variables before using the clients input with htmlentities() and some regular expression statement to filter out possible attack

Comment: Milan I would like to allow all HTML. Is there any tutorials that would help me understand for this? ;S

Comment: Hi; you may want to implement something like tinyMCE for your client's input (http://www.tinymce.com/) and also check this post for some good advice how to filter some extra spec. chars. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225472/validation-detected-dangerous-client-input-post-from-tinymce-in-asp-net

Comment: Could you be more specific how is your page being used ?

Comment: It's being used like a forum? So this is what it looks like with HTML: http://i.imgur.com/zEsSv.png and this is non-html: http://i.imgur.com/TWKm0.png

Comment: People post images, videos etc

Comment: Hi, I see. Perhaps someone more experienced could correct me if I am wrong but considering many security issues witch such forum model I myself would wanted to have 100% control over what is being posted and how it is going to impact the system. Therefore I would disregard any 3rd party libraries ........

Comment: .......with pre-written codes and used the above example. First I would allowed all HTML tags which are harmless, then I would identify all HTML characters and tags which could be potentially dangerous if misused and I would write specific rules for them (i.e.: <iframe> tag would have to have some rules attached etc..). Then I would test the code with all allowed HTML and see if it works and start with CSS. Then the rest of things (scripts, links, etc.) which you decide to allow to be posted.